# Intellij Idea not recognizing Freemarker syntax with less than sign

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax, freemarker

I have intellij 2017.1 and the Freemarker syntax is not recognized (and no intellisense) in my HTML when I use the inferior and superior sign for example `<#if>`

But it does recognize it when I use the new `[#if]`

When I tried to follow this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/template-languages-velocity-and-freemarker.html#template_data_language) I did not have any option of choosing the Freemarker template language.

I can't just change all of the occurrences to the new way of writing it because it's a huge project.

Example for the following screenshot, it should give me the intellisense for `<#if>` but it does not

[image]

When I use the new styling (starting from 2.3.4) it does give me the intellisense

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the problem. Do you use Ultimate or Community?

Comment: I'm using the ultimate version

Comment: Is there anywhere "[#" in this file before the text shown on screenshots?

Comment: nope! that is the first occurrence in the whole project. They are using the usual freemarker way with greater than > and less than <

Comment: still no answer?

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` of FreeMarker tags confuses the editor, so the solution is to use alternative syntax, instead of `<` use `lt` and instead of `<=` use `&lt;`.

Reference: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_alternative_syntax